# Can a wifi transmitter generate RF of different frequencies?

Tags: rf, wifi

If I have a micro controller (let's say a Raspberry Pi) that is able to connect to wifi (using a wifi transmitter), would it be possible to generate RF signals of other frequencies?  I figure it should be able to since wifi is just a 2.4 or 5.0 GHz RF signal and it must be able to generate signals if it is able to send information back to a router (or wherever else it is connected to).

Comment: In order to get FCC approval, the company that designed the transmitter will have very carefully designed it to not produce signals at frequencies other than 2.4 and 5.0 GHz.

Comment: Assuming you're in the US. In other countries, some other regulatory body will give them equal motivation to restrict the radiating frequencies.

Comment: How do you figure that is the case? In fact, synthesizers for the frequencies used in WiFi devices are interesting and versatile beasts, but I just don't see what the logical step is from "it's an RF signal" to "the device can generate other frequencies,too"?

Comment: Wifi has several channels around 2.4 and 5.0GHz.  So, yes, it can generate RF of various frequencies.  It CANNOT generate just any frequency you'd like in those ranges.  The firmware only allows transmitting on the proper channels.  Which channels are allowed depends on which country you are in - they have different laws and allow different channels to be used.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I guess I just figured that frequency could easily be changed since the signal generator is controlled digitally so it seems like you should be able to just change how fast it updates values (assuming you have full control over the software/hardware and aren't limited by permissions).

Comment: Yes and no. Yes is, you can generate anything with anything. No is, you are finding trouble by doing that. First of all, to control the IC to do it, you have to go through trouble to figure what the command is, which involves a lot of NDA and legal reviews, or reverse engineering. Even if you did it, you signal quality will be pretty bad, and again if you leak too much into the spectrum you are not authorized to use, radio authorities like FCC would visit you. I remember QCA engineers explicitly stated this is one of the things that " you can but you don't want to" do.

Comment: Another issue is, the antenna will not be well matched over the full octave between 2.4 and 5 GHz.

Comment: Sure you might be able to generate a signal, though I'm not even sure about that (is the LO range really that wide or will they just use one for 2.4 and one for 5 GHz?) . Even then, it's not unlikely that any amplifiers or filters on your rf section will pass signal. It seems very possible that they would be tuned to reject anything out of wifi bands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the components inside a WiFi AP (access point) may be able, if programmed appropriately, to be able to generate other frequencies, that interface is not available to a user of the AP, there just are no software 'knobs to twiddle' when connecting to it.

If you pull one apart physically and poke at the board, or hack it down to the firmware, then you may be able to coax other frequencies out of the components. You may rest assured that as the hardware has only been designed to handle the correct WiFi frequencies, any filters or line lengths in the AP may well be wrong for those other frequencies.

Now if you buy a 'software defined radio' (SDR), you'll find many of the same components in it that you'd find in an AP. The difference is that it's been designed to let you fiddle with it, it actually presents a programming interface to generate and receive different frequencies, and has a more general purpose RF path design.